# Why do I encounter Download Errors after transferring my code, that download Youtube Video and Audio, to a function to be executed with tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, youtube, youtube-dl, pytube

The code I used to download Youtube videos in MP4 format with the pytube library works perfectly fine and I am able to download videos. However, after putting the code in a function to be executed upon pressing a button on a Tkinter GUI, I am given an error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/eugesher/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-8-d7c65c063da0>", line 32, in MP4downloader
    yt = YouTube(yt_link)
  File "/Users/eugesher/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytube/__main__.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.video_id = extract.video_id(url)
  File "/Users/eugesher/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytube/extract.py", line 133, in video_id
    return regex_search(r"(?:v=|\/)([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11}).*", url, group=1)
  File "/Users/eugesher/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytube/helpers.py", line 129, in regex_search
    raise RegexMatchError(caller="regex_search", pattern=pattern)
pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: regex_search: could not find match for (?:v=|\/)([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11}).*
```

When I test the original code, independent from a tkinter and not placed in a definition, it still works with no such error encountered.

Here is the original code:

```
from pytube import YouTube
import os

spd = "/Users/eugesher/Downloads/Videos Pycharm"

def downloadYouTube(videourl, path):

    yt = YouTube(videourl)
    yt = yt.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4').order_by('resolution').desc().first()
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)
    yt.download(path)

downloadYouTube("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y9dr2zw-TXQ", spd)
```

This is the entire code in Youtube Tkinter Downloader:

```
import time
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as mb
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile
import pytube
from pytube import YouTube
import ffmpy3
import os
import youtube_dl
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL



YtD = Tk()
YtD.geometry("700x500")
YtD.resizable(0, 0)
YtD.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
YtD.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

YtURL = StringVar()
directory = StringVar()

details = Frame(YtD, width = 700)
details.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

title = Label(details,text = "Youtube MP4/MP3 Downloader")
title.place(x=275,y=50)

enter = Label(details, text = "Enter URL: ")
enter.place(x=125,y=90)

URL_in = Entry(details, width = 30, font=("Arial",18,""),
                 textvariable=YtURL)
URL_in.place(x=225,y=90)

choose = Label(details, text = "Choose File Path: ")
choose.place(x=110,y=120)



def open_file():
    file = filedialog.askdirectory()
    if file:
        global filepath
        filepath = os.path.abspath(file)
        directory.insert(END, filepath)

yt_link = YtURL.get()
d_link = []
save_path = directory.get()


directory = Entry(details, width = 30, font=("Arial",18,""))
directory.place(x=225,y=120)

browse = Button(details, text="Browse", command=open_file)
browse.place(x=565,y=120)

def MP3downloader():
    
    d_link.clear()
    
    video_info = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL().extract_info(
        yt_link,download=False)
    
    filename = f"{video_info['title']}.mp3"

    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'outtmpl': os.path.join(save_path,filename),
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
    }
    
    d_link.append(yt_link)
    
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download(list(d_link))
        




def MP4downloader():
    

    yt = YouTube(yt_link)
    yt = yt.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4').order_by('resolution').desc().first()
    if not os.path.exists(save_path):
        os.makedirs(save_path)
    yt.download(save_path)
    


d_4 = Button(details, text = "Download MP4", command=MP4downloader)
d_4.place(x = 350,y = 250)

d_3 = Button(details, text = "Download MP3", command =MP3downloader)
d_3.place(x = 200, y=250)

YtD.mainloop()
```

I am additionally facing issues with downloading Youtube videos in MP3 format with YouTube-dl library works perfectly fine and I am able to download mp3 audio. However, after putting the code in a function to be executed upon pressing a button on a Tkinter GUI, I am given another error:

```
ERROR: '' is not a valid URL. Set --default-search "ytsearch" (or run  youtube-dl "ytsearch:" ) to search YouTube
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/eugesher/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 815, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/eugesher/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 836, in __extract_info
    ie_result = ie.extract(url)
  File "/Users/eugesher/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/common.py", line 534, in extract
    ie_result = self._real_extract(url)
  File "/Users/eugesher/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/generic.py", line 2387, in _real_extract
    raise ExtractorError(
youtube_dl.utils.ExtractorError: '' is not a valid URL. Set --default-search "ytsearch" (or run  youtube-dl "ytsearch:" ) to search YouTube

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/eugesher/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-2-d7c65c063da0>", line 5, in MP3downloader
    video_info = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL().extract_info(
  File "/Users/eugesher/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 808, in extract_info
    return self.__extract_info(url, ie, download, extra_info, process)
  File "/Users/eugesher/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 824, in wrapper
    self.report_error(compat_str(e), e.format_traceback())
  File "/Users/eugesher/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 628, in report_error
    self.trouble(error_message, tb)
  File "/Users/eugesher/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 598, in trouble
    raise DownloadError(message, exc_info)
youtube_dl.utils.DownloadError: ERROR: '' is not a valid URL. Set --default-search "ytsearch" (or run  youtube-dl "ytsearch:" ) to search YouTube
```

Here is the original MP3 code. The MP3 Download using tkinter GUI can be found above under Youtube Tkinter Downloader:

```
import youtube_dl

video_info = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL().extract_info(
        url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fc-fa6cAe2c",download=False)
filename = f"{video_info['title']}.mp3"

spd = "/Users/eugesher/Downloads/Videos Pycharm"

ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'outtmpl': os.path.join(spd,filename),
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
        'preferredquality': '192',
    }],
}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(["https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fc-fa6cAe2c"])
```

I am unable to find the error in the Youtube Tkinter Downloader code and am clueless on how to approach the error. Greatly appreciate any advise and any explanation on why I am encountering the issue.

Comment: You need to get the URL and output path inside download functions.

Comment: Hello @acw1668 I believed I managed to accomplish this after rewriting my code since there were also multiple issues in between. Thanks!